# Boost type_traits is_array

Tags: c++, boost, type-traits

I have been trying to go through the Boost type-traits headers, and feeling quite sick now given the intense unreadability provided by countless #define. And then some more #define.

To be specific, I am interested in figuring out about the following 3 traits: if a type T is an array, a class or an enum.

Can anyone help suggest some way of deciphering the method behind the apparent madness? Like the theory behind how you figure out the trait from a type, any relevant reading material etc.

Comment: One way to get rid of countless ifdefs that bother you is to run the code trough preprocessor, i.e. using `-E` option with `gcc`. Then you can look trough the code that will be compiled for your platform by your compiler. Generally, traits are implemented using SFINAE, template (partial) specialization, and compiler-specific extensions.

Comment: +1 for your guts to dive into the boost headers. ;) I can actually only recommend that, especially the Boost.Function headers where quite educational for me.

Answer (score 4):

`is_array` is pretty simple and straight forward:

```
template<class T>
struct is_array{
  static const bool value = false;
};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct is_array< T (&)[N] >{
  static const bool value = true;
};
```

Just a simple partial specialization on a reference-to-array type.

`is_class` is a bit more complicated and relies on overload resolution and the fact, that classes and struct possess constructors (or destructors). As I'm currently on my iPod Touch, I can't really show an example. I'll edit one in as soon as I've access to a PC again.

`is_enum` relies on compiler intrinsics I believe, so no example there.

Note: Everything here is from memory, I could be wrong with the enum one.

Comment: You're right about `is_enum`, and the same is true for `is_pod`.

Comment: @ildjarn: I believe in Visual C++ every type trait is implemented using compiler intrinsics / extensions as far as I've seen. After all, the compiler knows best about types, no? `:)`

Comment: @Xeo : What I meant to say is that those two type traits in particular can _only_ be implemented with use of compiler intrinsics, while the rest can be implemented with simple metafunctions.

Comment: @ildjarn: If I was at a PC right now and not on my iPhone, I'd take that as a challenge. ;)

Comment: @Xeo: +1. More on the compiler intrinsics/extensions please.

Comment: @Fanatic23 : For VC++, these are documented here: [Compiler Support for Type Traits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177194.aspx)